# jQuery .load() returns unexpected token

Tags: jquery

I found many threads which could not help me so I thought I'll ask this question.

I use `jQuery` function `.load()` to load a file into my page. Here you can see the snippet:

```
$('.page-box[data-target="hdr-panorama-2"]').load("panoramabox/kueche/output/panorama.html");
```

If I add this to my code I got an error in the console:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < (jquery-latest.js:612)
```

I don't think that is a jQuery issue. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `panoramabox/kueche/output/panorama.html` doesn't have any script tags does it? guess that's a stupid question, of course it does! otherwise you wouldn't be getting this error. Ideally you don't want to load any content that contains script tags with .load because it can be unpredictable when the code executes relative to the html being appended to the page.

Comment: Hmm okay. Do I understand it right that I cannot use .load() to do this? Are there some alternatives?

Comment: The least intrusive option would be to use a selector with `.load` that narrows down the content that gets pulled from the request. `$(target).load("/foo/bar/foobar.html #thecontainerid")` note however this means if the html you are loading requires additional javascript to set it up, you'll need to add that javascript to the complete callback of the .load method.

Comment: Unfortunately, the suggestion with adding the id to the link doesn't work :/

Comment: didn't really expect it to, as it's very dependant on the structure of your html. You'll want the id of the parent of the html you want to grab.

Comment: Omg.. I forgot to upload the edited file to the ftp server. The error is now away but it doesn't load the file to the page (logically). You said something about to add the JavaScript to the callback of the .load method? Can you give me an example? :)

Comment: I think it should work even with `script` tags but script tags will be (probably) stripped out by `jQuery` but no error should not be popped up.

Comment: The error pops up if I work with script tags

Comment: Sorry! I meant `The error should not be` :p

Comment: The `load` works with `script` tags and script runs, I've tested it.

Comment: Hmm, but why am I getting an error if I use script tags with .load()?

Comment: Make sure you don't have an un expected `<` in anywhere, maybe at first of the page, could be a typo but not sure.

Comment: You should post your code (including the `html`).

Comment: What you have in `panorama.html` ?

Comment: Omg I found the issue. I took a closer look to every warning and error the console has throwed. And then I've seen that there was a wrong link... What a mistake >.< Thank you for supporting :)